# Simplify CubeRoot of meter cubes

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions, units

Why Mathematica doesn't simplify CubeRoot of meter cubes to meters?

```
r = Quantity[10, "Meters"];
v = 4/3 r^3 Pi;
CubeRoot[% * 3/4 / Pi]
```

returns

```
Surd[Quantity[1000, ("Meters")^3], 3]
```

instead of 10m, which was what I would expect.
I think this has something to do with the fact that a the root could be a complex number.
I searched the web and found some hints about using assumptions, but it didn't work for me.
Please, could anybody help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you, L-

Answer (score 3):

It appears `Surd` is not integrated into `Quantity` (and it probably should be). This auto simplifies:

```
r = Quantity[10, "Meters"];
v = 4/3 r^3 Pi;
(%*3/4/Pi)^(1/3)
```

> ```
> Quantity[10, "Meters"]
> ```

Comment: Thank you Chip for your answer. I didn't realize I could use ^ operator! Anyway I think it doesn't work with Power[] function too.

Comment: @Luca `x^y` is shorthand for `Power[x, y]`, so both should work.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it works also with Power[] function. Thank you Chip.